# Regardless of comment length, I always get error: "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length"

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

Recently I have found that any comment I attempt to make on any post produces a "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length" error. This happens even for comments that are well over the 15 character minimum. Anyone know what is going on?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)

Desktop: KDE

Browser: Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: This appears to be specific to Google Chrome. I added this comment using FireFox.

Comment: Leaving this comment works fine on my computer using Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit) when used on OS X 10.10.5 (14F2511). As such, looks like it is related to your OS and/or Desktop.

Comment: Another Chrome comment, just to verify @WillemRenzema's results. (I've also posted various comments on SO and at least one other SE site today.) In my case, an Ubuntu-derived linux with Gnome rather than KDE.

Comment: YOU SHOULD TRY SHOUTING! MAYBE IT CAN'T HEAR YOU.

Comment: Chrome 63.0.3239.108 also on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit and I've had no issues.

Comment: This is a test with all Chrome extensions disabled.

Comment: So it appears that some extension that I have enabled under Chrome is causing this problem. I will experiment and try to determine which extension is the cause, Will post results later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the culprit turns out to be an extension named "CorrectEnglish for Browsers". Disabling that extension allows me to submit comments.

Comment: Try Grammarly for Chrome instead?

Comment: Looks like questions about the stack overflow comment system are off-topic for meta-stack overflow. Glad I got the comments above that helped me solve the issue before the police found me out. :-)